# How to make mu4e and Emacs the default email program?

Tags: email, mu4e

On `macOS`, when I click an email link `<a href="mailto:...">`, it opens `Mail.app` that ships with `macOS`. How can I change it to `mu4e` in Emacs?

Comment: Do you mean by default in your operating system or within emacs, e.g. with an org-mode link?

Comment: I mean operating system default, so clicking that link in a browser opens Emacs in mu4e instead of `Mail.app`.

Comment: This reddit post might be helpful https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/6lh2pp/using_emacs_as_default_mailer_on_macos/

Comment: Yes, it works, although only with the Emacs server running. I'd like it to work without the Emacs server.